# Web development in .NET - Which techniques to use to build and consume your own API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-web-api

We are trying to make up our minds where to start with a new project of upgrading our website. As we have upgraded our old back-end system in .NET we really want to keep working in C# for many reasons like (but not limited to) TFS integration, the development environment, and testing, Azure integration, integrated security, proper documentation, etc.

What we also know we want to accomplish is to start with a web based API and consume our own services, first on a regular website, later also on mobile devices. We have been playing around with WCF (OData enabled) Data services and the new Web API which comes with MVC4.

My personal preference is working with the Data Services, as more of the OData standard is implemented, like the $select option, which makes the API we would create very simple and extremely useful, and we can ensure we only request the data we use from the client, in JSON, XML, and probably other formats we will not immediately use.

Now as our first project will be to implement a website that consumes either the Data service, or the Web API, which frameworks should we look at to consume the services from the client side. Ideally we would like to serve the website from another machine and have the client to connect to the API using Ajax (or JSONP) to read from the service (in a later stage also the CUD actions).

For creating the new website we want to buy a set of tools, and we have evaluated Telerik, DevExpress and Ext.NET, but none of these seem as compatible with either of these services as they claim on their site (but perhaps I am missing something). We want to try to stay away of creating our own javascript.

I guess my questions are the following:

- Which of the techniques for the API is better and why? DataService
  seems to be quite old - will it still be supported in the future? Is
  there a third option I should evaluate?
- Did someone choose to take on a similar project and can you share your experiences?
- Which of the frameworks of Telerik, DevExpress, Ext.NET or any other is more
  useful to consume any of these APIs from the client side?
- Should we use WebForms or MVC and why?

Answer (score 2):

For a recent project we did we avoided commercial third-party libraries entirely - for various reasons: we haven't been impressed with how they compare to open-source libraries (not GPL for obvious reasons, but mostly BSD/Apache), but also because a lot of the things we were trying to do were really simple and it's just as quick to build our own platforms than it is to learn an existing platform and then spend time getting it to do what we want.

For our back-end API we went with an entirely RESTful service written against WCF. It returns pure and simple XML using our own POCO data contract objects - this meant we could develop our own clients in multiple languages (including .NET, PHP, and Javascript using jQuery) very quickly and easily. Avoid SOAP like the plague. However it took us ages to get WCF to work in a proper RESTful way - if we were doing the project from the start then we would probably write our own RESTful web-server that sits on top of HTTP.SYS instead of plugging into IIS as it needlessly complicates things at times (for example, our service uses HTTP Basic Authentication for access-control, something IIS likes to get in-between). Then there are also issues with "base URLs" where IIS and WCF duke it out. WCF in IIS needs work on user-friendliness.

For client-side we have the option of allowing Javascript to connect directly to the service, but we saw no real performance gains, in the end we decided to get the scripts to do everything via the website's own AJAX interfaces. Besides, exposing the back-end datasource or API is revealing implementation details and isn't good software engineering.

We eschew client-side frameworks for the reasons I gave above. If you're good with XHTML/CSS then you can write your own web-based widgets easily and ensure they're built for your application. I've seen too many applications that just sprinkled Telerik/DevExpress/etc controls over a page and the result was a slow, cumbersome mess due to all of the imported client-side script files and resources.

WebForms is dead and ASP.NET MVC is the future. The code you'll write against it will be a lot cleaner, organised, and coherent. The removal of "controls", lifecycles, viewstate all simplifies things and eliminates a lot of ASP.NET's voodoo (such as what happens to controls added after Page_Load). I never want to see WebResource.axd in my life again (it makes debugging and customizing client-side scripts on the go very hard).

The bad news is that if you or your team don't have much experience doing things the "right way" (i.e. not using visual designers for HTML, doing excessive DataBinding, or just plonking an `<asp:DataGrid>` on a page) then you will have an uphill struggle as you unlearn bad habits.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your advice David. The main reason we would want to stay away from writing our own JS/CSS is because our old site could have been a lot better and cleaner. Supporting all browsers is (or at least was) a nightmare, and most of those libraries promise to work in most of them. 

You are talking about open source libraries - Would you name a few that I should look at?

Comment: jQuery and jQuery UI do everything we need. We avoid ASP.NET AJAX (despite its stated compatibility with jQuery) for performance and user experience reasons.